# How to get absolute value after subtracting the following value by the previous value in a file with multiple colomns?

Tags: linux, command

I have a file contains numbers.

1 34 44 44 46

5 35 40 40 45

6 36 28 30 40

My goal is for each column to have the absolute value after subtracting the following value by the previous one as the below:

1 34 44 44 46

4 1  4  4  1

1 1  12  10 5

I used

```sh
cat File.txt | awk '{for(i=1; i<=$i-1 ;i++)$i=(a[i]-=$i)}END{print $1 >=0 ? $1 : 0 - $1}'
```

but I got only the absolute value of the subtractions of the first column.
I tried also the $0 instead of $1 but i didn't get the correct output. 
Does anyone has an idea how to improve the above command in order to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**test.awk**

```
function abs(x){
    return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)
}
{                               

    for(i=1; i<=$i ;i++) {a[i]=abs(p[i]-$i)}
}
{
    for(i=1; i<=$i ;i++) {p[i]=$i;}     
}
/[0-9]/{
    for (i in a) {printf "%s ",a[i]};print "";print ""
}
```

run as follows:

```sh
 awk -f test.awk <path_to_your_file>
```